# Chart custom labels not appearing on X axis

Tags: c#, charts

I've tried a couple of the solutions posted and none of them seem to work.

```
salesTitle.Text = chartTitle;
this.chtSales.Series.Clear();
this.chtSales.Titles.Add(salesTitle);
this.chtSales.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;

// Try for Custom Labels
foreach (string monthName in monthArray)
{
    string sMonthName = monthName;
    sMonthName = char.ToUpper(sMonthName[0]) + sMonthName.Substring(1);
    CustomLabel monthLabel = new CustomLabel();
    monthLabel.Text = sMonthName;
    this.chtSales.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(monthLabel);
}
```

I think I may need to add some parameters to the `CustomLabel` function call but I can't work out what they should be?

On the bright side the data is showing correctly.

Comment: You need to set the FromPosition and ToPosition to suitable values. [Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+CustomLabel+FromPosition+) - Also : Your x-values needs to be numeric (or dates)..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Links Rufus, indeed the FromPosition and ToPosition needed to be set. For anyone else battling the same issue, code below works though I am adding Month names to the x AXIS.

```
// Try for Custom Labels
for(int i = 0; i < monthArray.Length; i++)
{
   string sMonthName = monthArray[i];
   sMonthName = char.ToUpper(sMonthName[0]) + sMonthName.Substring(1);
   CustomLabel lblMonth = new CustomLabel();
   lblMonth.FromPosition = i;
   lblMonth.ToPosition = i + 1;
   lblMonth.Text = sMonthName;
   this.chtAccum.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(lblMonth);
}
```